# Create Tables in Snowflake Dynamically (Columns Unknown) from CSV files in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dynamic, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-ingestion

**Experts I need your guidance and help here. Here is my Scenario!**

I have an AWS S3 Bucket where I get a lot of CSV files (different structures - file names are different, columns get added or dropped for the same file every time - It is a very dynamic setup). I will not know column details or data structure in advance.

All that I need to do is, each time a file gets into the S3 bucket, I need to trigger a lambda in python which has to do the following

1. Create a table in Snowflake (Warehouse, DB, Schema established) for each file based on the Name of the file And
2. Read the header fields from the CSV file, and create the columns dynamically for the above table

> (If I knew the column names in advance, I could create a control table
> with metadata [columns, data types, default values, PK, etc] using
> which I can create dynamic SQLs to create the tables using a snowflake
> stored procedure - But this is not what I am looking out for)

Could you please throw your thoughts and expertise in order to have a Robust Automation solution to create tables dynamically and load the data into respective tables in Snowflake?

**Appreciate your time and Help in advance**

Comment: While this question is too broad to be answered well here on SO, I think the biggest hurdle is determining column types from analyzing flat files. Perhaps a tool like AWS Glue Crawler may help. I believe you can query Glue Catalog metadata through Athena and from that dynamically generate your DDL that would then be applied in Snowflake. Alternatively, I believe Pandas Dataframes make determination on column types when reading in a flat file. I'm not sure how robust that is, but if you are looking for a lighterweight route, that may be an option.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to see if I can leverage Panda Dataframes for this. Do you have any reference URL where I can see such similar examples? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's the `dtypes` of the dataframe that you are after: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html